Doing a kind of Excel scrollable table with tkinter
I want to display a table (variable number of rows) with tkinter where:

The size of the window is adjsuted to the content
Vertical scrolling is proposed if the there are too many rows
Vertical scrolling can be done with the wheelmouse inside the table (as in Excel)
Copying the value of one cell is possible (right click on the cell)

This post (Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter) is helpful to understand scrolling with tkinter...but doesn't fulfill with all requirements above.

The main tricks are:

Only few tkinter objects are scrollables (Canvas are scrollable)
Inside the canvas, don't use grid or pack (you would loose scrollability) but the method dedicated to canvas called 'create_window'
Inside the window of your canvas create a frame...like that inside your frame you can well use pack/grid methods.
Resize the canvas to the content....each time content is added into the frame (<Configure> event)
The way mousewheel event is caught depends on your OS (in the example below event.delta management is for windows)
Well break any mousewheel event in the scrollbar (to not conflict with mousewheel event you programmed)

Here a solution example:
# Standard libraries
import tkinter as tk


class ResultWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        # Initialize the GUI
        super().__init__()

        # Create the main widgets
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", width=25)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        # Add them to the toplevel layout
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        # Bind events to the widgets
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)
        self.vsb.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: "break")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)

        # Link Canvas scroll with Scrollbar
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

        # Add the frame to define the way
        self.l_cell = None

        # Add arbitrary content (to create our table)
        self.add_content(200, 5)
        
    def add_content(self, rows, cols):
        
        # Declare functions to manage code labels highlighting
        set_color = lambda event: event.widget.config(bg="grey")
        reset_color = lambda event: event.widget.config(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        
        for col in range(cols):
            for row in range(rows):
                # Add the cells to the grid
                text = f"row: {row}, col: {col}"
                self.l_cell = tk.Label(self.frame, text=text, relief="solid")
                self.l_cell.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")
                
                # Bind each cell to events
                self.l_cell.bind("<Enter>", set_color)
                self.l_cell.bind("<Leave>", reset_color)
                self.l_cell.bind("<Button-3>", self.on_click)
                
    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        # Resize the canvas to fit with the content
        self.canvas.config(width=self.canvas.bbox("all")[2],
                           height=self.canvas.bbox("all")[3])

        # Adjust the scrollable scope to the new size of the canvas
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        # Update the scroll according to the mousewheel scroll size
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

    def on_click(self, event):
        # Clear the clipboard
        self.clipboard_clear()
        # Get the Label widget code and add it to the clipboard
        self.clipboard_append(event.widget.cget("text"))
        
app = ResultWindow()
app.mainloop()

